# How to set color in a custom view which do not have a function for this?

Tags: android, colors, android-view, attr

I want use a custom checkbox in my application android and this custom checkbox do not have a function to set color and in the example they set color on xml using (http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto) like (app) and set color that way app:stroke_color="#2196F3" I would like to know how set color programmatically , link for custom checkbox https://github.com/lguipeng/AnimCheckBox

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the library. They do not have a `setter` for `stroke_color`. The only workaround here is to use `Reflection` to access this private field directly. [Reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) is almost always a bad practice in java. But if you really want to do it, you can do it this way:

```
AnimCheckBox checkbox = (AnimCheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
try{
  Field field = checkbox.getClass().getDeclaredField("mStrokeColor");
  field.setAccessible(true);
  field.setInt(checkbox,Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));
  checkbox.invalidate();
}
catch (NoSuchFieldException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IllegalAccessException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can set the circle color in the same way. For circleColor, the field name is `mCircleColor`.

Comment: It's worked, thank you so much, and thank you for warning that is not a good pratice too, I will consider your comment and try find another way to do in the future. :D